# How to remove multiple elements from Observable array without subscribing to it

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my angular 4 app, I came across a scenario on removing few elements from an observable array containing a custom type. Here I have another Observable array of elements to be removed. Is there a way to remove elements of one Observable array from another without subscribing to them.

For example, say if I have observable arrays of **allCustomers** and **orderedCustomers**.

How to I get customers who aren't ordered anything. (allCustomers - orderedCustomers = ?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) is what you want:

```
import {combineLatest} from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest'; // import for rxjs 5+

// these are your existing Observables...
const allCustomers$: Observable<Customer[]>;
const orderedCustomers$: Observable <Customer[]>;

// this will be an Observable of customers with no order
const customersWithNoOrders$: Observable<Customer[]> =
  combineLatest(
    allCustomers$,
    orderedCustomers$,
    (allCustomers, orderedCustomers) => {
      return allCustomers.filter(customer => !orderedCustomers.includes(customer));
    }
  );
```

Comment: You don’t need to turn your Observables into Subjects. I’ll update my answer to use Observables...

Comment: Dear Miller, Thanks for the support, small adjustment did the trick. const customersWithNoOrders$ = combineLatest(
  allCustomers$,
  orderedCustomers$,
  (allCustomers, orderedCustomers) => {
    return allCustomers.filter(customer => !orderedCustomers.includes(customer));
  }
);

Answer (score 0):

you have to use filter pipe to do that.

More information here : https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html

```
const source = Observable.from([
        {
            id: 1,
            ordered: true,
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            ordered: false,
        },
                {
            id: 3,
            ordered: true,
        }
    ]);

source.pipe(filter(customer => customer.ordered === false)).subscribe(customerNotOrdered => {
    console.log(customerNotOrdered);
});
```